# Why don't all of the factor variables appear in the legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm pretty new to plotting using matplotlib and I'm having a few problems with the legends, I have this data set:

```
        Wavelength       CD  Time
0          250.0  0.00000     1
1          249.8 -0.04278     1
2          249.6 -0.03834     1
3          249.4 -0.02384     1
4          249.2 -0.04817     1
...          ...      ...   ...
3760       200.8  0.99883    15
3761       200.6  0.50277    15
3762       200.4 -0.19228    15
3763       200.2  0.81317    15
3764       200.0  0.90226    15

[3765 rows x 3 columns]
```

Column types:

```
Wavelength    float64
CD            float64
Time            int64
dtype: object
```

Why when plotted with Time as the categorical variable all the values are not shown in the legend?

```
x = df1['Wavelength']
y = df1['CD']
z = df1['Time']

sns.lineplot(x, y, hue = z)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Lineplot]

But I can plot using pandas built in matplotlib function with a colorbar bar like this:

```
df1.plot.scatter('Wavelength', 'CD', c='Time', cmap='RdYlBu')
```

[image: scatter plot]

What's the best way of choosing between discrete and continuous legends using matplotlib/seaborn?
Many thanks!

Comment: Just a note: `sns.lineplot(x, y, hue = z)` can be `sns.lineplot(x='Wavelength', y='CD', hue='Time', data=df1')`

Comment: Also note that `sns.lineplot` supports an option `legend='full'`